# xslt replace value of multiple elements

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to replace values of multiple elements of an input xml. The input file has around 300 elements of which I need to replace around 100 elements. I have used identity template before, but I think it would require me to write 100 different templates each for replacing a single element value. I am not very good at xslts, so, am I thinking it right, or is there a better an elegant approach? Please advice.

**Edit**

Here is the [Link of sample input xml](http://wikisend.com/download/587070/BusinessPartner.xml).

The output will have almost the same structure, but different values for some of the elements.

Comment: Post an example input and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a link with input xml. Please see the edit.

Comment: What should be changed in the input XML?

Answer (score 0):

Well, something I did similar before before so I am happy to share ... modified to your example BUT does not do the value mapping, it does name mapping. 
First create a simple mapping file like this (NOTE: you would need the namespaces to do this right

```
    <env:map xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <elem old="CardCode" new="CodeCardNEW"/>
        <elem old="CardName" new="IAMNew"/>
    </env:map>
```

Then one template will do you with a lookup. There are likely better ways to do the mapping, I am just for-each looping over them all ... a key would be better. But this gets you there.

Output from your file with above:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Body>
<GetByKeyResponse>
  <BOM>
    <BO>
      <AdmInfo>
        <Object>oBusinessPartners</Object>
      </AdmInfo>
      <BusinessPartners>
        <row>
          <CodeCardNEW>CR43WEB</CodeCardNEW>
          <IAMNew>Zack Burns</IAMNew>
          <CardType>cCustomer</CardType>
            ...
```

And here's the XSL:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:param name="map" select="document('map.xml')/env:map"></xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:variable name="newname">
            <xsl:call-template name="namesub">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="name()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:element name="{$newname}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="namesub">
            <xsl:param name="name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="newname">
            <xsl:for-each select="$map/elem">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@old = $name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@new"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($newname) > 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$newname"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should be able to adapt this as long as you have a match on name ... if the name is the same in different hierarchies of the XML, you would need more work.

Comment: If you are only doing value mapping, you would delete the @new attribute, add the new values in the map and then move and slightly modify the call-template that maps values into the template match for text(). Should be easy enough to get there from the above.